# Can same-sex sex committed in (e.g.) western countries be prosecuted in (e.g.) Morocco?

Tags: family-law

Pretty much the title, is same-sex sex also illegal when not committed in a homophobic country when visiting there? E.g. could social media posts put you on trial when you'd visit such countries?

Answer (score 3):

That depends entirely on the laws of the country involved. Some countries do make having homosexual relations a crime, indeed a very serious one. I haven't heard of one which prosecutes for being in a same-sex marriage or relationship entered into in another country, but such a country could hold such a trial if it chose to. Perhaps more likely, if a same-sex couple visited such a country, evidence of a continuing same-sex relationship might be treated as evidence of same-sex sexual acts, and thus of a crime under that country's laws.

Comment: I was told by a muslim colleague that there are countries with Sharia law that actually state that four actual witnesses are needed for a successful prosecution which will end in death. Death penalty is obviously bad, but when they say "four actual witnesses" they mean it. Don't have any details. So if you have three adventurous couples and two of the men want to try out gay sex... Don't.

Comment: I wish that any downvoters would leave a comment indicting what they think is wrong with this answer. In the absence of a comment, I cannot improve the answer, others cannot use the reasons to write better answers, and readers have no idea why someone objects to the answer. Such a downvote seems pointless.

Comment: A few years ago there was a case in the USA where a judge refused to divorce a same-sex marriage because same-sex marriage was not recognised in that state. In a deeply Muslim state the very concept of same-sex marriage might not  even exist, and therefore not be punishable.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

I cannot speak specifically to Morrocon law but there are plenty of precedents for imposing domestic law on acts that happen outside the geographic jurisdiction of a state.

For example, every jurisdiction outlaws piracy, both the old-fashioned eyepatch and parrot type as well as the music download type.

Many countries also punish their own citizens and residents who travel for unlawful sex - usually with children but, in principle, there is no reason it couldn't be applied to any "criminal" act - homosexuality, adultery, pre-marital sex etc.

Of course, in Morocco, if homosexual acts are illegal, then they are illegal for everyone who is there irrespective of if they live there or are just visiting (diplomatic immunity excluded).

Comment: I was reading the "code penal" which outlaws homosexuality in Morocco, and the "[procedure penale](https://learningpartnership.org/sites/default/files/resources/pdfs/Morocco-Penal-Code-2018-French.pdf)" which does state that there acts outside of the Kingdom may be tried under particular conditions, which then couldn't find.

Comment: Wrong link, this is the [procedure penale](http://www.vertic.org/media/National%20Legislation/Morocco/MA_Criminal_Procedure_Code.pdf), article 748: "... L'accomplissement au Maroc du fait principal est attributif de compétence aux juridictions du royaume même lorsque certains des éléments constitutifs ont été réalisés en pays étranger et quelle que soit la nationalité des coauteurs. La compétence des juridictions marocaines pour juger le fait principal s'étend à tous les faits de complicité ou de recel même perpétrés hors du royaume et par des étrangers."

Answer (score 0):

The relevant legal concept is "extraterritorial jurisdiction", which is where a country asserts jurisdiction over acts performed outside its borders. An example is [18 USC 2423](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2423), where a US person travels abroad to engage in any illicit sexual conduct – which is defined to cover sex with a person under age 18 with complications, but uncomplicatedly *any* commercial sex with a person under 18. However, prostitution is legal in a number of countries and the age of consent is under 18 in many countries (as low as 12). The act is legal in e.g. Thailand, but you can be prosecuted in the US (however, the US law limits prosecution to cases where the "motivating purpose" is illicit sexual conduct).

In Kenya, under the [Sex Offenses Act of 2006](https://www.ilo.org/wcmsp5/groups/public/---ed_protect/---protrav/---ilo_aids/documents/legaldocument/wcms_127528.pdf) §41(1) says

> A person who, while being a citizen of, or permanently residing in
> Kenya, commits an act outside Kenya which act would constitute a
> sexual offence had it been committed in Kenya, is guilty of such an
> offence and is liable to the same penalty prescribed for such offence
> under this Act.

Under [Penal Code 162 and 165](https://www.ilo.org/dyn/natlex/docs/ELECTRONIC/28595/115477/F-857725769/KEN28595.pdf), homosexual acts are felonies (the specific verbiage is "carnal knowledge of any person against the order of nature" and "indecent practices between males").

Countries only claim extraterritorial jurisdiction for people that they have some legal control over, for example citizens and residents. A person who does not have the relevant legal connection to Kenya, who has outside of Kenya committed an act that would be illegal in Kenya, is not subject to prosecution in Kenya if they visit there (as long as they do not commit the act in Kenya).

Comment: "*Countries only claim extraterritorial jurisdiction for people that they have some legal control over,*" Israel claims, or used to claim extraterritorial jurisdiction over any participant in the Holocaust. It was under this law that [Adolf Eichmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Eichmann#Capture) was captured (or abducted), tried, and executed. There are other cases where a country claims jurisdiction over a person who has never been under its laws.

Comment: "Countries only claim extraterritorial jurisdiction for people that they have some legal control over, for example citizens and residents." In addition to the example mentioned by @DavidSiegel , Salman Rushdie was sentenced to death by Iran, despite not being an Iranian citizen and, to my knowledge, never visiting Iran.